# Looping through a long list in VBA and pulling data on the way down

Tags: excel, vba

I found it difficult to put this into a succinct question, so I'll try my best to explain here.

I have a large list in Excel that looks something like this: (The Original List)

```
1
Term1
Term4
Term6
2
Term1
3
Term2
Term3
Term5
4
Term1
Term2
Term3
Term5
```

Now, I've written a series of scripts to convert this list into a different form, like this: (The Finished Product)

```
Term 1: 1 2 4
Term 2: 3 4 
Term 3: 3 4 
Term 4: 1
Term 5: 3 4
```

However, I feel that my script is very inefficient. First, it pulled all the Terms that appeared in the Original List, aligning them into what would become Column A of the Finished Product.

Then, it rearranged the Original List so that the 'headers' (1, 2, 3, 4...) all appear in the top row, essentially making it horizonal rather than vertical. I'll refer to this as a 'The Library'.

And finally, it contained a loop saying "Wherever Term1 appears in The Library, copy whatever appears in row 1 of that column" (which would be 1, 2, and 4).

However, is there a more efficient way to do this, that doesn't involve making 'The Library'? Could I write something that goes through the Original List and say "wherever 'Term1' appears, pull the first number that appears above it," and so forth.

Apologies if I did a poor job of explaining. Any suggestion or starting point would be very much appreciated.

Edit: The current script, for those interested. The sheet "List" contains the list of Terms in The Finished Product. While the Sheet "Library" contains the Original List re-arranged horizontally.

```
Sub ListLibraryCompare()

    Sheets("List").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Comparison").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("List").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Keyword As Range
Dim Chunk As Range
Dim Library As Worksheet
Dim List As Worksheet
Dim Bottom As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim X As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = 1
X = 0

Set Library = Sheets("Library")
Set List = Sheets("List")

While i <= 7000
Set Keyword = List.Range("A" & i)
Set Bottom = Library.Range("A200").Offset(0, X)
Set Rng = Library.Range("A1").Offset(0, X)
Set Chunk = Library.Range(Rng, Bottom) 'Sets Chunk to the range between cells     Rng and Bottom

If IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = True Then
i = i + 1
X = 0
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Chunk, Keyword) = 0 Then 
X = X + 1
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Chunk, Keyword) >= 1 Then '
Rng.Copy
Keyword.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
X = X + 1
End If
Wend 

End Sub
```

Comment: a starting point would be to show us the actual vba code that you have? hard to evaluate code that we cannot see

Comment: perhaps question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as long as code is actually working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to set and maintain, and much faster, to use variant arrays and a user defined object.  Using a Class Module, we would define an object, which I named `cTerm`, consisting of each `Term`, as well as a collection of the `Headers` that apply to that `Term`.  Then create a collection of these objects, and output it the way you want.

Below is the code, hopefully annotated well enough for you to be able to adapt it to your real data.  The potentially difficult part is determining whether an entry is a `Header` or not.  I chose to determine that by using the `IsNumeric` function.  But this may need to be altered depending on the nature of your real data.

Be sure to rename the Class Module:  **`cTerm`**

### Class Module

---

```
Option Explicit

'RENAME this module  cTerm

Private pTerm As String
Private pHeader As String
Private pHeaders As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pHeaders = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Term() As String
    Term = pTerm
End Property
Public Property Let Term(Value As String)
    pTerm = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Header() As String
    Header = pHeader
End Property
Public Property Let Header(Value As String)
    pHeader = Value
End Property

Public Function ADDHeader(Value As String)
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore duplicate headers
        pHeaders.Add Value, CStr(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Property Get Headers() As Collection
    Set Headers = pHeaders
End Property
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CollectTerms()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim cT As cTerm, colT As Collection
    Dim sHeader As String, lHeaders As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Set Source and Results worksheets, Results range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Get Source data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Collect header list for each Term
Set colT = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    'Is it a header?
    If Not IsNumeric(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
        Set cT = New cTerm
        With cT
            .Term = vSrc(I, 1)
            .ADDHeader (sHeader)
            colT.Add cT, CStr(.Term)

            Select Case Err.Number
                Case 457
                    colT(CStr(.Term)).ADDHeader (sHeader)
                    Err.Clear
                Case Is <> 0
                    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
            End Select

            'keep track of column count
            lHeaders = IIf(lHeaders > colT(CStr(.Term)).Headers.Count, lHeaders, colT(CStr(.Term)).Headers.Count)
        End With

    Else
        sHeader = vSrc(I, 1)
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Create Results Array
ReDim vRes(1 To colT.Count, 1 To lHeaders + 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1)
    With colT(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Term
        For J = 1 To .Headers.Count
            vRes(I, J + 1) = .Headers(J)
        Next J
    End With
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=False
End With

End Sub
```

---

Comment: This is a great starting point for me, thanks. I'll need some time to digest it myself, though. Thanks a million!